Error while installing fop package on ubuntu linux using apt-get install fop
apt install fop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package fop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'fop' has no installation candidate

OS:  Ubuntu 5.15.0-107-generic
Tried to download and install manually from
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/
it is not giving the fop command but Installation was succeeded. Nothing found on installation path than a pom file.
Tried this link one also:
download , uncompress and add to PATH
Ant: How to Install a Compiled Program (FOP 1.0)

Is this a programming question? Should you maybe try Ask Ubuntu instead?
